# JNDI Service provider for the file system

Tags: java, jndi

I was looking for the Java Naming and Directory Interface (JNDI) service provider for the file system.

As far as I know, Oracle ships  bundled with the JDK only service providers for RMI, DNS, LDAP and COS. It looks like Sun used to provide one, because my Google search returned a number of Web-sites and forums including Coderanch where people suggested downloading the file system SP from [Sun's JNDI page](http://java.sun.com/products/jndi/downloads/index.html), but that page now redirects to Java Technetwork's main page. Also, [Oracle's JNDI page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jndi/index.html) gives no information about the file system SP while in the [JNDI trail of the Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/basics/prepare/software.html) they suggest you to download it from the above-mentioned JNDI page and provide examples of using it to look up a name. Search on the Oracle's Web-site also did not yield anything.

My question is composed of two parts:

1. What happened to the Sun's JNDI filesystem service provider and is it still  possible to get any of its versions somehow/somewhere?
2. Are their any alternative filesystem SPs for the JNDI?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: It's only a toy. Don't make this part of your future. It hasn't been maintained for over a decade. Use an LDAP server.

Comment: @EJP thank you for your suggestion. I need it for operations on the local filesystem for a desktop gui, for example recursively searching a directory, reading file attributes, searching for a file based on its attributes, etc. That's why introducing any type of server into the equation seem to make the solution more heavyweight. So if it is not meant for a production use, may be one can use it as a sample to develop his own filesystem SP?

Answer (score 4):

Not found in maven central and mvnrepository.com and jfrog.
Currently (2015) found at oracle archive to download manually and for maven a similar dependency here is the following pom.xml.

[See MVNRepository.com](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.messaging.mq/fscontext). Not updated for a decade now, as of 2021-03 the last update was 2011-04.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.messaging.mq</groupId>
   <artifactId>fscontext</artifactId>
   <version>4.6-b01</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to download this library from oracle's [archive downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-java-plat-419418.html).
This page contains long list of downloads. Try [Ctrl+F] for "File System Service Provider, 1.2 Beta 3". 
The jar file is 14 years old :) It was released on Mar 29, 2000.

Answer (score 1):

You can possibly dowload it from [Maven Central](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jndi/fscontext/1.2-beta-3)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jndi</groupId>
    <artifactId>fscontext</artifactId>
    <version>1.2-beta-3</version>
</dependency>
```

Searching for alternative leads to [SwiftMQ](http://www.swiftmq.com/developers/howto_jndi_fscontext/) implementation

Comment: This jar is not found anymore.