# JNDI implementation for working with java objects

Tags: java, jndi

I've just started to learn JNDI. As I understood it's an INTERFACE for different naming services.

I decided to use it as a registry for objects I have. For example, I have object configuration and I want to get it from another object by JNDI. Of course I could use some static ways for example `Registry.get("configuration")` but I want to start using JNDI. And I need it for java se application.

> Important - objects mustn't be persisted to db/files etc.

But what implementation of naming service should I use? If someone provided an example it would be great.

Comment: Use this link ->
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16914368/jndi-service-provider-for-the-file-system?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JNDI is a naming provider. Usual registries (besides JavaEE, will come later to that) are LDAP or DNS. Both systems are organized with hierarchies and provide lookup of data.

In the Java Enterprise world, JNDI is used to retrieve ConnectionFactories, EJB's, DataSources, configuration objects and many more, which are configured within the application server container.

The JNDI starting point in Java is the `InitialContext`. There are implementations which allow use within JavaSE (like [SimpleNamingContextBuilder](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/jndi/SimpleNamingContextBuilder.html) within tests) but in general, building an own [InitialContextFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/spi/InitialContextFactory.html) is an advanced topic.

Comment: I implemented my own ContextFactory. Simple and what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Simple-JNDI contains a pure in-memory implementation of a JNDI Service. It offers a way to access properties in configuration files via JNDI lookups. If you don't need this feature, you can only use the JNDI Implementation like this:

```
Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
env.put("jndi.syntax.direction", "left_to_right");
env.put("jndi.syntax.separator", "/");
env.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.osjava.sj.memory.MemoryContextFactory");
Context ctx = new InitialContext(env);
Context subCtx = ctx.createSubcontext("sub1");
subCtx.bind("name", "value");
String name = (String) subCtx.lookup("name");
assertEquals("value", name);
name = (String) ctx.lookup("sub1/name");
assertEquals("value", name);
```

More information is available here: [Simple-JNDI](https://github.com/h-thurow/Simple-JNDI)